# Strongest electrical wire at AWG 24

Tags: cables, wire, electricity

Is there any ultra strong electrical wire at about AWG24 (0.22mm)? I want something that would be strong as a steel wire rope but also with low resistance that can used as electrical wire.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90029/discussion-on-question-by-astra-strongest-electrical-wire-at-awg-24). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using 5V ("5V and the current 0.5A" from a comment), you probably have two limitations, one based on heating and one based on voltage drop. The second may well be the long pole in the tent.

Incidentally, your 0.22 mm diameter number is wrong for AWG24 wire diameter (it's actually a bit over 0.5mm diameter), so it's not clear to me whether you are keying off the gauge or the diameter.

In any case, you might be able to kill two birds with one stone by using a switchmode regulator along with a relatively high voltage such as 24VDC.

Assuming, say, 85% efficiency, 2.5W at the destination will require about 3W input or 125mA at 24VDC. The loop resistance of 0.255 mm (AWG 30) steel wire 1m long (x2 for return path) would be around  8 ohms, so it would drop about 1V, costing about 5% in efficiency. Not too bad. One watt spread over 2m of wire is not too much either.

Comment: OP needs to specify the length required, and the max acceptable voltage drop. Then one can back calculate the minimum copper cross section from there. One can even use that to electroplate copper on GI wire.